# TypeError when trying to access function inside ModelType Class

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose-schema, nestjs

I'm working on NestJS-MongoDB application, and using Typegoose for modeling. I have created model for the Org as below.

**org.model.ts**

```
export class Org extends Typegoose {

    @prop({ required: true })
    name: string;

    @prop({ required: true, unique: true, validate: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/ })
    email: string;

    @prop({ required: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 12, match: /^(?=.*\d).{6,12}$/ })
    password: string;

    @prop({ required: true, unique: true })
    phone: number;

    toResponseObject(){
        const {name, email, phone } = this;
        return {name, email, phone };
    }
}
```

**org.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class OrgService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Org) private readonly OrgModel: ModelType<Org>) { }

    async findAll() {
        const orgs = await this.OrgModel.findOne();
        console.log(orgs);
        console.log(orgs.toResponseObject()); // Throws error here
        // return orgs.map(org => org.toResponseObject());
    }
}
```

and from Provider class I'm trying to access `toResponseObject()` but it throws `TypeError: orgs.toResponseObject is not a function`. Why provider class unable to access that function?.

Comment: I don't think @nestjs/mongoose supports typegoose, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typegoose

Comment: Yeah, right! This is the library I'm using to model.

Comment: Have you made sure to call `TypegooseModule.forRoot` in your main module and `TypegooseModule.forFeature([Org])` in your `OrgModule` or whatever exports / provides that service? Edit: also are you certain that the org is actually being returned ie. `findOne` is not returning `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Yeah those imports are taken care. Everything works fine if I don't use `orgs.toResponseObject()`,  `console.log(orgs);` returns one object with no issue, but the problem is it cannot access the function inside the `Org`

Comment: I'd give `@instanceMethod` on that function a shot if you haven't already.  It's a decorator in the typegoose library.

Comment: Oh yeah, there you go! :D . You saved my day mahn. Thanks a lot. post it as Answer. :)

Comment: Glad I could help, I'd take a look into `class-transformer` too nestjs has a guide on that.  It might make your serialization to JSON a bit easier to manage

Comment: Sure, I'll look into that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typegoose has a decorator `@instanceMethod` you can use so that when the plain objects get serialized the function will get added to the class as well.  You could change your example to something like

```
import { instanceMethod } from 'typegoose';
// ...

export class Org extends Typegoose {

  @prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @prop({ required: true, unique: true, validate: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/ })
  email: string;

  @prop({ required: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 12, match: /^(?=.*\d).{6,12}$/ })
  password: string;

  @prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  phone: number;

  @instanceMethod
  toResponseObject(){
    const {name, email, phone } = this;
    return {name, email, phone };
  }
}
```